# Custom Oauth Server and ampersand in query string issue

Tags: php, laravel, oauth2-playground

I have been trying to use the oauth2 playground with the Laravel `oauth2-server` bundle and ran into an issue.  I'm using `header('location:` to take me back to google after the authorization has happened.   The string I'm putting into the redirect is

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?state=1&code=d84024740acc22646b9636421406c88abeab9c8e
```

However, when I get to it the `&` has been replaced with `&amp;` which is causing the playground to not go to step 2.  What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using Laravel's `Redirect` class, rather than a header? It should handle the encoding better:

```
Redirect::to('https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?state=1&code=d84024740acc22646b9636421406c88abeab9c8e');
```